# Flashing/ blinking a textbox with one command button

Tags: excel, vba

I know this Code for creating a flashing Cell with two command buttons:

```
Sub start_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(“00:00:01”), “next_moment”
End Sub

Sub end_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(“00:00:01”), “next_moment”, , False
End Sub

Sub next_moment()
If Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
start_time
End Sub

VBA Code for First Command Button (“Start Blinking”)

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call start_time
End Sub

VBA Code for Second Command Button (“Stop Blinking”)

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call end_time
End Sub
```

What I want to do now is to make a TextBox flash, which stops automatically after 10 seconds.This should also be controlled by a command button. But in this case only by one, because the blinking stops automatically. My idea was to work with the background color of the TextBox, but I could not implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    PlayStopMacro = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
    Else
    PlayStopMacro = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
    next_moment
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "StopMacro"
    'Keep thi odd number to keep textbox backcolor white
    End If
End Sub
```

in Module

```
Public PlayStopMacro As Boolean

Sub next_moment()
If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else

    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment"
End If
End Sub

Sub StopMacro()
PlayStopMacro = False
Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: when i implement this code only the command button turns green. unfortunately no flashing. It is supposed to be like a car blinker. Which automatically stops blinking after a few seconds.

Comment: It worked with every click, but I get this error msg: The macro <macro name > cannot be executed. The macro may not be available in this workbook, or all macros may have been disabled. - for nextmoment and stop macro. sorry but it looks like i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes. I made a complete new excel-sheet for testing it. Do I have to copy paste it all into the VBA window?

Comment: Yes .. copy sheet code in sheet (In VBA on left hand side you will see Sheet 1.. Double click on that) .... and insert module code in a module .. Also better to make command button click macro private ..like in your question Private Sub .. May be you have pasted all macro in Sheet 1.  ..You need to insert module for nestmoment and stopmacro

Comment: works perfectly. is there a way that onely the textbox is flashing? i tried it with `Sub next_moment()
If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    If Sheets("Idee_02").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
    Sheets("Idee_02").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
    Sheets("Idee_02").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Idee_02").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment"
End If

End Sub` in the module, but then it does not flash anymore.

Comment: edited answer.. please check removed cells(1,1) lines

Comment: Sorry my bad, I copied the version before.

Comment: Yes, it is working. That was the last step for my little project. Thanks to you, it is almost finished. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put it all in the same module)

```
Option Explicit
Public dteStartTime As Date

Sub start_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment"
End Sub

Sub end_time()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment", , False
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub next_moment()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
If dteStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:10") <= Now Then
  end_time
Else
  start_time
End If

End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
dteStartTime = Now
Call start_time
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `Public` counter variable (`x`) which counts to 10 and then stops calling `start_time`. This means that `end_time` can be removed from the code:

```
Public x

Sub Button1_Click()
Cells.Clear
Cells(1, 1) = 1
x = 1
start_time
End Sub

Sub start_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment"
End Sub

Sub next_moment()
With Cells(1, 1).Interior
  If .ColorIndex = 6 Then
    .ColorIndex = 0
  Else
    .ColorIndex = 6
  End If
End With
x = x + 1
Cells(1, 1) = x
If x < 10 Then start_time
End Sub
```

The `with` statement makes the code more manageable. The `cells(1,1)` value keeps track of the counter, and these can be removed.

Comment: Thank you. I used the code from Naresh, but your code is also working fine.